# How to add a separator cell/uiview between cells in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

What's the best way to separate cells with a separator UIView or cell? Like:

```
31.10.2013
message: hi!
message: hey!
01.11.2013
message: hi again!
```

The best example is the Whatsapp chat app, they separate messages with a small separator line with the date of the messages. The "7. Mai 2013" in this screenshot: http://images.ifun.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/ipad-screen.jpg

I was thinking in sections but maybe it is too complex for a simple work. I also thought in adding a UILabel to the first cell of a certain day but this is not so nice.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think section is a way to go, because it suit the situation which group messages with same date(section). If you use core data, that would be even easier task with `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Actually I'm using CoreData... I think I will go in the section direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can keep record of the cells that are different and return a different cell in the cellforIndexPath, or use sections, both options seems good.

It's not a simple task, although it's not very complex once you have decided an approach.

Comment: A different cell is not good because if I delete one cell with the "31.10.2013", I would reload the whole table to show the same title in the next cell. I think I will go in the section direction. Thank you!